# Autohotkey - Want to launch program and bring it's window to the front

Tags: script, autohotkey

I want an Autohotkey script which launches a new instance of Chrome and brings that new window to the forefront (active window).

My script is:

```
#c::
Run "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" -start-maximized --new-window www.google.com
WinActivate, Google ; Window title is "Google"
```

What happens is this: if, prior to activating the hotkey there is any arbitrary window in focus, the browser instance launches in the background which is not what I want.  If however the desktop or Taskbar has focus then my new Chrome window comes to the forefront as I want it to.

Comment: 1. What happens if you just launch Chrome without any params? 2. Try specifying `#WinActivateForce` at the top of your script.

Answer (score 3):

Most likely WInactivate does not work because you need to add `SetTitleMatchMode, 2` at the top of your script. To test if WinActivate really works use this:

```
SetTitleMatchMode, 2
#c::
Run "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" -start-maximized --new-window www.google.com
WinWait, google ;Give Chrome a chance to start before testing
IfWinExist, google
{
    WinActivate, google ; Window title is "Google"
    MessageBox, OK
}
Return
```

If you do NOT see the OK message, your Winactivate still waits for the correct title. Once you are sure this works, you can reduce is back to:

```
SetTitleMatchMode, 2
#c::
Run "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" -start-maximized --new-window www.google.com
WinWait, google ;Give Chrome a chance to start before testing
WinActivate, google ; Window title is "Google"
Return
```

Comment: librink - I was wrong - still sporadic.

Comment: Matt, Still sporadic what?Doesn't Chrome launch, is Google.com not showing, or is your "Google" window not activated? B.t.w. As far as I know even with SetTitleMatchMode, 2 WinActivate is still case sensitive.

Comment: My question was poorly worded. I have fixed it. I am reading your answer - I am not sure if this would work in the common case where I have many Chrome windows (and instances) at the time I hit the hotkey. I might have to set a unique window title if I can and activate that.